# Deleting notes in ipod

Tags: gmail, notes.app

All my notes are synced to my gmail account and can be accessed. Now if I delete all my notes on my ipod, would it also delete all my notes in my gmail because it syncs. 
I do not want the notes in gmail to be deleted.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the notes from the app, then yes, they'll be deleted from Gmail. However, if you just want to take the notes off the iPod, you can just switch off "Notes" for your Gmail account under Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you confirm my inference that if I have deleted all my notes on my ipod after having switched off 'Notes', and then on a latter day would want to sync with gmail the notes i had stored latter, then it would wipe off the existing notes in Gmail as it has been deleted in the app.